# Div.Owl-Controls is being set to 'display:none'

Tags: owl-carousel

..And I don't know why.  I am trying to emulate a page that already has owl.carousel on it, and I have loaded all the correct CSS and JS files.  However it seems that the `owl.carousel.js` file is setting the div to not display, because I end up with:

`<div class="owl-controls clickable" style="display: none;">`

Why is this?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough items in your carousel yet to warrant adding the "prev/next" buttons. Perhaps you have only three items, and you are displaying three items at a time and so it doesn't need the prev/next buttons. Add more items and the "display: none" inline style will disappear.